# Looping everything between two objects in a list

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm working on a block coding engine in Roblox, I have some blocks made like move, change size and rotate. But I can't figure out how to make a loop, I have to find every item between two items in a for i,v in pairs loop.

```
for i, block in pairs(script.Parent.Parent.Script:GetChildren()) do
            wait(0.1)
            if block.Value == "MoveX" then
                game.Character.Position = UDim2.new(game.Character.Position.X.Scale, (game.Character.Position.X.Offset + block.EpicValue.Value), game.Character.Position.X.Scale, game.Character.Position.Y.Offset)
            end
            if block.Value == "MoveY" then
                game.Character.Position = UDim2.new(game.Character.Position.X.Scale, game.Character.Position.X.Offset, game.Character.Position.X.Scale, (game.Character.Position.Y.Offset + block.EpicValue.Value))
            end
            if block.Value == "Rotate" then
                game.Character.Rotation = game.Character.Rotation + block.EpicValue.Value
            end
            if block.Value == "SizeX" then
                game.Character.Size = UDim2.new(game.Character.Size.X.Scale, math.abs(block.EpicValue.Value), game.Character.Size.X.Scale, game.Character.Size.Y.Offset)
            end
            if block.Value == "SizeY" then
                game.Character.Size = UDim2.new(game.Character.Size.X.Scale, game.Character.Size.X.Offset, game.Character.Size.Y.Scale, math.abs(block.EpicValue.Value))
            end
            
            if block.Value == "LoopStart" then
                -- start loop
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a foreach loop, use a while loop. Then you can easily convert this while loop into a state machine:

```lua
local i = 1
local instructions = script.Parent.Parent.Script:GetChildren()
while i < #instructions do
    -- fetch current instruction
    local block = instructions[i]

    if block.Value == "MoveX" then
      --...
    elseif block.Value == "LoopStart" then
        if not insertYourLoopCondition then
            i = instructionIndexOfLoopEnd
        end
    elseif block.Value == "LoopEnd" then
        i = instructionIndexOfLoopStart - 1
    end

    -- next instruction
    i = i + 1
end
```

In words: you need jumps. A loop consists of a condition and a "jump" at the end to return to the condition.
A condition is a "conditional jump".
When generating your blocks you need to gather the target indices of all jumps once.